# How to set hotkey to move cursor out of quotes/parenthesis?

Tags: visual-studio-code

In Sublime I could easily set a more complex hotkey that lets me exit quotes and parenthesis by pressing Enter. It is here below:

```
    // Move out of single and double quotes with `Enter`
    {
        "keys": ["enter"],
        "command": "move",
        "args": {"by": "characters", "forward": true},
        "context": [
            { "key": "following_text", "operator": "regex_match", "operand": "(?:\"|').*", "match_all": true },

            { "key": "preceding_text", "operator": "regex_contains", "operand": "(?:\"|')", "match_all": true }
        ]
    },
```

In VS Code, is there any way to achieve this? This in `keybindings.json` moves the cursor, but it is active when I don't want too. Thanks.

```
    { "key": "enter",    "command": "cursorRight",
                         "when": "editorTextFocus" }
```

Answer (score 16):

Check out this extension which does what you want - https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=albert.TabOut

And you can find the implementation here - https://github.com/albertromkes/tabout

Comment: Hi Rob, I've tried that extension before, but it doesn't work well enough on its contextual awareness. It actually has an unintended side effect of being a tab-in as well instead of just a tab-out which makes it impossible to add new tab spacing at the start of a line that begins with quotes.

[Issue #5](https://github.com/albertromkes/tabout/issues/5)

Comment: A little late to the party, but the tab-in issue should be solved

Answer (score 6):

In VS Code, you can type the closing quote (i.e. if using double quotes)

```
{shift+'}
```

while you are INSIDE the quotes to have it exit outside the closing quote. This also works for parenthesis and brackets, just type the closing one (i.e. ) or ]). You can also jump straight to a new line by pressing

```
{ctrl+enter}
```

which exits out of any brackets, parenthesis, quotes you are already in. These 2 methods here should be embedded in standard VS Code AFAIK.

Comment: ctrl+enter works like a charm.

Answer (score 3):

I found `Ctrl+Shift+\` useful for moving out of quotes. Also, it could be remapped by searching `jumpToBracket` in Keyboard Shortcuts.

See full VSCode keyboard binding [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings).