# After VS Code auto closes a quote, parentheses, or bracket, what key do i hit to move to the next position after that closing mark?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'll start typing something in VS Code like `class="bob"`, and as soon as I type the opening `"` mark, VS Code will auto populate the closing `"` mark as well.  Very helpful!  BUT, once I'm done entering my string of information, I find myself having to adjust my keys on my keyboard to `arrow right` past the character that was automatically added, then hit a space, and continue on my coding way.

However this can interrupt my typing flow, as it would be just as easy if not easier for me to type the closing `"` mark myself without adjusting my hand from the default keyboard position.

This happens with other characters, too, not just quotes.  Parentheses, brackets, single quotes, and similar items that show up in pairs.

When I watch videos of some people coding, they seem to gracefully whiz by those auto-added closing punctuation marks, so it makes me think there is something I'm missing in how I accept that automated input. Some way that is more zen like than using a right arrow.

Comment: Can't you just type the closing brace or quote or ...? For me, if the cursor is before an auto-inserted closing brace or quote, the new one is not inserted, as if I just pressed the right arrow.

Comment: "Can't you just type the closing brace or quote .." Yes, I can. Doing so made me wonder if I was not benefitting from the auto-close, hence my question.  If this is what people do, then ok, I can do that.  I just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing something.

Comment: I use shortcuts to move cursor right and left like ctrl+a (left index finger on my layout) and ctrl+k (Right index fingre) in addtion to tripple a and tripple k, again as keyboard shortcut, so that i dont have to lift my hands to fish for arrow keys. Yes you can set sequential shortcuts.

Comment: Found a similar question here -  [How to set hotkey to move cursor out of quotes/parenthesis?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40205809/6908282)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several options:

1. Type the character that added automatically. For example, if you type `{` and automatically VS Code added `}` you can also type `}` to continue typing whatever you want. VS Code is smart to not doubling the automatically added character
2. Use `End` key
3. Use `arrow right` key

I think the VS Code team didn't find it needed to add some special key for this need, since all these options are also one key each.

Comment: Thanks - I'll mark this as the accepted.  I wanted to make sure I'm not missing anything else.  I'm not, although I never thought about using the `end` key, which is easier for me to hit that `arrow right`, so thanks, I learned something!

Comment: Happy to help. Good luck

Comment: another option is to use `Ctrl + Right Arrow` to jump to the end of current word. This helps if you're in the middle of an existing text and you want to jump out of quotes/brackets, but not jump to the end.

Answer (score 3):

There's an extension that allows `tab` out of closing `quotes` and `braces`.

It's called (appropriately)... `TabOut`!

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=albert.TabOut

Comment: This blew my mind and is exactly what I needed, thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me;

- Go to VS Code settings
- Search "autoclose"
- Disable "Auto Closing Tags"
- Change "Auto Closing Quotes" from 'always' to 'never'
- Change "Auto Closing Brackets" from 'always' to 'never'

Comment: Thank you - I hadn't thought to look for this.  It's helpful to know I could do it if I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

On macOS:

`Ctrl+F` to move forward

`Cmd+Enter` to jump to the next line